# Angular 2 stop an observable

Tags: angular

I have the following observable for countdown calculations:

```
Observable.interval(1000).map((x) => {

       let date1= Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000);
       let date2 =  Math.floor(this.future.getTime()/1000)+600;
    this.diff = date2 - date1;
}).subscribe((x) => { 
        this.message = this.dhms(this.diff);
      });
```

I want to stop the observable when `this.diff` <= 0. (since the countdown is.. finished)
How I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let sub = Observable.interval(1000).map((x) => {
...
sub.unsubsribe();
```

Comment: Unsuscribe not stoping the timmer on my case, I have this `this.count = 100;
        this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, 1000)
            .take(this.count)
            .map(() => this.count = this.count-10);
        this.sub = Observable.interval(1000)
            .subscribe((val) => {
                if(this.count===0){
                    this.sub.unsubscribe();
                }
                           
            )` and it still showing numbers on timmer and is going negative

Comment: Sorry, I can't read this code. Please create a new question and add the code so that it's properly formatted.

Comment: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812624/stop-angular2-countdown) there you go.