# Stop Angular2 CountDown

Tags: angular, timer, countdown

I'd like to stop my `Countdown` but it does not stops and still running I have this :

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

sub: Subscription;
countDown;
count;
this.count = 100;
this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, 1000)
        .take(this.count)
        .map(() => this.count = this.count-10);

this.sub = Observable.interval(1000)
        .subscribe((val) => {
            if(this.count===0){
                this.sub.unsubscribe();
            }
        });
```

and when the timer equals to 0 it goes to -10, etc...

Is there another way to stop that timer?

Comment: TypeError: _this.countDown.unsubscribe is not a function

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a function called `stopTimer()` that is :

```
stopTimer(){
        this.countDown = null;
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

It will stop the `Timer` and will stop the `CountDown`.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't unsubscribe to the right variable. Here is how you should do :

```
this.count = 100;
this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, 1000)
  .subscribe(x => {
      this.count = this.count - 10;
  });

this.sub = Observable.interval(500)
  .subscribe(x => {
     console.log(this.count);
     if (this.count === 0) {
        this.countDown.unsubscribe();
     }
});
```

[Here is a StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-timer-obs)

Comment: I tried it with sub and countDown and the same time, you mean that I have to unsubscribe the countDown?

Comment: TypeError: _this.countDown.unsubscribe is not a function

Comment: Why _this.countDown.unsubscribe(); instead of this.countDown.unsubscribe(); ?

Comment: Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161286/discussion-between-skizo-oziks-and-br-julien).